# Mockaroo Formulas for random date range using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a data field using [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com) and they say they have Ruby support but I know nothing about Ruby so I am trying to find out how to do a field that will randomly choose between the 3 options.

```
now() or
now()+days(-1) or
now()+days(-2) or
now()+days(-3)
```

**Idea 1**
I was initially thinking something using random like `now()+days(this.rand(-3))`

**Idea 2**
I also thought of using or logic like `now() or now()+days(-3) or etc...`

This answer may end up being different than a typical ruby solution since Mockaroo has their own little API to use too... Appreciate any help that can be given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had to use the random function first and pass in min and max date parameters.

```
random(now()+days(2), now()+days(-3))
```

Comment: Author of Mockaroo here.  I probably would have used now() + days(random(-3,2)).  Didn't realize random could take date arguments, but it's cool that it worked :).